# Using ubuntu hotspot and squid

Tags: server, proxy

I've installed a second wireless card on my laptop.
Using the hotspot function on Ubuntu 13.04, I'm able to share the internet connection with my pupils (they have no login for the wireless network).

I've also installed squid, but I had to set the proxy manually on my test tablet.

- How do I load the proxy automatically on connecting clients?

The proxy is transparent for the moment, but I want a certain control.I think I can find out how to block certain domains myself, but I want to be able to block sites at my lessons too.

- How do I block domains on the fly?

Related to this, I would like to cut off internet access and let them return to my local host at any time, for instance to wrap up the lesson before the bell.

- How do I redirect them to my local web server, on the fly?

If the pupils are busy, I want to use the projector to show a constant flow of fetched URLs, so they can help each other and I can keep a lookout while walking amongst them. I know I can use tail on the access.log, but

- Are there other tools to get a list of accessed URLs, without refusing write access on the log file (preferably in Python)?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Shell script to get list of accessed URLs
http://mkeadle.org/squid/squidwatch.sh

Block on the fly (didn't check)
http://mkeadle.org/squid/squidmanage.sh

Comment: Load automatically:
http://wiki.squid-cache.org/SquidFaq/ConfiguringBrowsers#Fully_Automatically_Configuring_Browsers_for_WPAD
http://wiki.squid-cache.org/Technology/WPAD